# how to save excel file with all its existing parameters/settings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I have excel file (.xlsx) with many sheets which contains many rows, columns, different column colors, size and so on... I just have to add some new rows(work with data not with as it called "conditional formatting"?).
I use pandas to import and save excel file. I'am also quite new to python.. I could not find the answer yet.

So my question is, is there any possibility to open excel file and update it with all its existing parameters like colors, font size and so on??

I'm trying to open and save it like:

my_excel_file = pd.read_excel(r'my_file.xlsx')
my_excel_file.to_excel('my_file.xlsx'), index = False)

all the sheets are gone, only one sheet saved, the same with colors, font size and so on.

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears, you are opening one tab/sheet within Pandas and then saving that dataframe to a single sheet as well.

If you want to load all the data from the various tabs of your excel workbook, first load them and assign a name to them and thereafter save each of those dataframes to a specific tab in excel, for example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='tab1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='tab2')
```

Thereafter specify that you want to save these dataframes in different worksheets as opposed to overwriting the same sheet:

```
df1.to_excel('name_of_excel_file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
df2.to_excel('name_of_excel_file.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

Perform as many times as need to - you can even create a function/loop to do it for you if it is repetitive.

Comment: Thanks, I meant, when saving excel file and open it, everything is laid out not the same as it was before (column width, size are different, there are no more colors). And I dont know why, but still using your code it saves only 1 sheet.